# mm menu & prototype.js conflicting, html vanishes on using search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/kjyzu/9/)**

I am using **[mm menu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/)** & **[prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/)** every thing is fine except when i used menu search bar entire html of menu section vanishes.

Using chrome i have found that on line #2049 of prototype.js

```
element.innerHTML = content.stripScripts();
```

is removing the html.. & if i remove this line from prototype.js many other stuff in my project starts giving erros.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**CODE FROM DEMO:**

**HTML**

```
        <nav id="my-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a>Home</a>

                </li>
                <li> <em class="Counter">3</em>
 <a>About us</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a>History</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a>The team</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a>Our address</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#my-menu").mmenu({
        searchfield: true
    });
});
```

**Files being used in DEMO:**

- **[mmmenu css](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/src/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css)**
- **[mmmenu js](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/src/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js)**
- **[Prototype.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js)**
- **[demo.css](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/demo/demo.css)**
- **[jquery 1.10.1](//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js)**

Comment: P.S I am tired atm & going to sleep i will be back after 8hrs Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pro tip: don't use Prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the jsFiddle is using Prototype 1.7 - if you update to the latest version (1.7.2) released April 2014 it fixes the issue.

Please take a look at the fiddle (revision 10) updated with 1.7.2

Comment: neat, i hope updating prototype version will not effect rest of the my project ...

Comment: between 1.7 and 1.7.2 Prototype tried to limit the breaking API changes, but fixed alot of things under the hood as well as bugs that were found.